# MySql Why Indexes increases performance

Tags: mysql, sql

Im new to databases to please just dont blast me.

I have read a lot about MySql Indexes, i know how they should be used.
What i deducted is that the only thing that increase performance when using indexes is that the information in the index tables is ordered. Am i correct ?

ps: if is correct, what doest it change to create an index asceding ordered or descending ordered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a weird question, that are half-answering yourself. Indexes increase performance, because they are ordered. It's of course faster to find John Smith in a telephone book that is ordered by names rather than in a telephone book that is unordered.

As to ascending and descending indexes: There is little difference. Indexes are usually binary trees that can be read in either direction of course. So for finding entries there is no difference. But in some rare cases you can benefit from the entries found in the same order as specified in your query's `ORDER BY` clause. My recommendation: Don't specify an order for your indexes; it is so very rare for a query to benefit from an index being descending that you can ignore this feature :-)